# How to print all the integer points on and inside the graph of the equation?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, regions

Consider an equation $(x-1)^2/25+(y+2)^2/9=1$.

```
(x-1)^2/25+(y+2)^2/9==1
```

**How can one print all the integer points on and inside the graph of the equation?**

I tried many times but failed to solve it.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 7):

This [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html)s the numbers, as you asked.

```
Module[
 {
  eqn = (x - 1)^2/25 + (y + 2)^2/9 <= 1,
  region,
  pnts
  },
 region = ImplicitRegion[eqn, {x, y}];
 pnts = ({x, y} /. Solve[{x, y} \[Element] region, Integers]);
 Print[pnts];
 ]
```

> ```
> {{-4,-2},{-3,-3},{-3,-2},{-3,-1},{-2,-4},{-2,-3},{-2,-2},{-2,-1},{-2,0},{-1,-4},{-1,-3},{-1,-2},{-1,-1},{-1,0},{0,-4},{0,-3},{0,-2},{0,-1},{0,0},{1,-5},{1,-4},{1,-3},{1,-2},{1,-1},{1,0},{1,1},{2,-4},{2,-3},{2,-2},{2,-1},{2,0},{3,-4},{3,-3},{3,-2},{3,-1},{3,0},{4,-4},{4,-3},{4,-2},{4,-1},{4,0},{5,-3},{5,-2},{5,-1},{6,-2}
> }
> ```

But probably you actually want to do something with them, not just `Print` them.

```
Module[
 {
  eqn = (x - 1)^2/25 + (y + 2)^2/9 <= 1,
  region, pnts
  },
 region = ImplicitRegion[eqn, {x, y}];
 pnts = ({x, y} /. Solve[{x, y} \[Element] region, Integers]);
 Show[
  Region[region],
  ListPlot[
   pnts
   , PlotStyle -> Red
   , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]

  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Alan thanks for checking and warning me. I had two versions, and pasted the wrong one. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

```
sol=NSolve[(x - 1)^2/25 + (y + 2)^2/9 <=  1, {x, y}, Integers]
Show[{ RegionPlot[(x - 1)^2/25 + (y + 2)^2/9 <= 1, {x, -5, 7}, {y, -6,2}],ListPlot[{x, y} /. sol]}, PlotRange -> All,AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

solves the problem!

Comment: To answer the question as stated, I think you need to change `==` to `<=`

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann you should have plotted the ellipse for completeness, +1

Comment: @José Antonio Díaz Navas: Done, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
reg = Region @ ImplicitRegion[(x - 1)^2 / 25 + (y + 2)^2 / 9 <= 1, {x, y}];
lattice = Tuples[Range[Ceiling @ #, Floor @ #2]& @@@ RegionBounds[reg]]; 

Show[reg, RegionIntersection[reg, Point @ lattice]]
```

[image]

```
Show[reg, Graphics@{Red, PointSize @ Large, Point @ Select[lattice, RegionMember[reg]]}]
```

[image]

```
coords = Pick[lattice , RegionMember[reg, lattice]]
```

> {{-4, -2}, {-3, -3}, {-3, -2}, {-3, -1}, {-2, -4}, {-2, -3}, {-2,  -2}, {-2, -1}, {-2, 
>     0}, {-1, -4}, {-1, -3}, {-1, -2}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 
>       0}, {0, -4}, {0, -3}, {0, -2}, {0, -1}, {0, 
>       0}, {1, -5}, {1, -4}, {1, -3}, {1, -2}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 
>       1}, {2, -4}, {2, -3}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {2, 
>       0}, {3, -4}, {3, -3}, {3, -2}, {3, -1}, {3, 
>       0}, {4, -4}, {4, -3}, {4, -2}, {4, -1}, {4, 
>       0}, {5, -3}, {5, -2}, {5, -1}, {6, -2}}

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to graphics primitives, than you can just use [`RegionIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection). For example, the disk is:

```
disk = Disk[{1,-2}, {5,3}];
```

and a lattice that encompasses the disk is:

```
lattice = Point @ Tuples @ Replace[
    CoordinateBounds[disk],
    {a_, b_} :> Range[Floor[a], Ceiling[b]],
    {1}
];
```

The intersection is then:

```
inter = RegionIntersection[disk, lattice]
```

> Point[{{-4, -2}, {-3, -3}, {-3, -2}, {-3, -1}, {-2, -4}, {-2, -3}, {-2, -2}, 
>   {-2, -1}, {-2, 0}, {-1, -4}, {-1, -3}, {-1, -2}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 
>      0}, {0, -4}, {0, -3}, {0, -2}, {0, -1}, {0, 
>      0}, {1, -5}, {1, -4}, {1, -3}, {1, -2}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 
>      1}, {2, -4}, {2, -3}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {2, 
>      0}, {3, -4}, {3, -3}, {3, -2}, {3, -1}, {3, 
>      0}, {4, -4}, {4, -3}, {4, -2}, {4, -1}, {4, 
>      0}, {5, -3}, {5, -2}, {5, -1}, {6, -2}}]

Visualization:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[LightBlue], disk, Black, lattice, Red, inter}]
```

[image]